# Why not include CSRF protection for GET apis?

Tags: security, csrf, csrf-protection

I was reading up on CSRF and came across this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36671/csrf-token-in-get-request

Multiple people online have also seem to indicate that one should not protect GET requests against CSRF. However, I am confused by why.

If your GET request contains sensitive information (like say personal info for a user), then you would want to protect it against CSRF right? Otherwise an attacker can steal personal info.

I get that you shouldn't include the token in the GET URL because those may be logged. However, can't you just include them in a custom header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRSF attacks are blind. They typically send a request without being able to read the result of the action. The reason here is the Same Origin Policy.

SOP prevents you from reading RESPONSES received by other origins, meaning that you can't access the private stuff anyways.

CRSF protection instead protects REQUESTS in the sense that it adds a token which symbolizes that the request is started by the web app itself

Comment: So are you saying that if `xyz.com` makes a GET request to `abc.com`, then there's no way `xyz.com` can actually read the response from `abc.com`?

Comment: Also is there any downside to adding csrf protection on GET routes?

Comment: So, in a typical card attack, somebody embeds a form or an action of o website you might have an account on in another website. As an example, you visit a forum and on this forum an attacker was able to embed a form that starts a money transfer request of your bank. Maybe you were currently logged in in your bank account. If there were no CSRF tokens, that request might have worked.

Comment: Now, regarding the questions: the first one is basically right. If the user does not disable SOP in his browser and if and.com doesn't have permissive allow-origin headers, requests starting from the front end of xyz.com cannot read the response

Comment: And while I can't think of a downside per se about adding CSRF tokens in a get request, you have to understand that they really are not necessary. If you think you need them, it might be that you have some design issue (E.g. you are treating the tokens as a sort of session authentication check)

Comment: Got it that is very helpful. No I don't need it, but I am storing the csrf token alongside my session so one database call gets both pieces of information whether or not I need it. So I thought I would check the csrf token anyways since it's already there. Does that sound like bad design to store csrf token with the session ID?

Comment: You mean server side: no, not a bad design at all. Btw, owasp is a good source when it comes to these issues: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)